# Qt: executable does not regenerated

Tags: c++, qt, executable

I have simple Qt program. When running `make` it gives error which is 1200 lines long

```
make: Circular main.o <- QThread dependency dropped.
In file included from mythread.h:4,
                 from main.cpp:3:
./QThread:1: error: stray '\127' in program
./QThread:1: error: stray '\2' in program
./QThread:1: error: stray '\1' in program
./QThread:1: error: stray '\1' in program
In file included from mythread.h:4,
                 from main.cpp:3:
./QThread:1:8: warning: null character(s) ignored
./QThread:1: error: stray '\2' in program
./QThread:1:18: warning: null character(s) ignored
./QThread:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '>' token
./QThread:1:20: warning: null character(s) ignored
./QThread:1: error: stray '\1' in program
./QThread:1:22: warning: null character(s) ignored
./QThread:1: error: stray '\240' in program
./QThread:1: error: stray '\21' in program
./QThread:1:28: warning: null character(s) ignored
./QThread:1: error: stray '@' in program
./QThread:1:34: warning: null character(s) ignored
./QThread:1: error: stray '@' in program
./QThread:1: error: stray '\24' in program
./QThread:1:43: warning: null character(s) ignored
./QThread:1:54: warning: null character(s) ignored
./QThread:1: error: stray '@' in program
./QThread:1:56: warning: null character(s) ignored
./QThread:1: error: stray '\8' in program
./QThread:1:58: warning: null character(s) ignored
./QThread:1:60: warning: null character(s) ignored

...

./QThread:16: error: stray '\255' in program
./QThread:16: error: stray '\255' in program
./QThread:16: error: stray '\235' in program
./QThread:16: error: stray '\156' in program
./QThread:16: error: stray '\137' in program
./QThread:16: error: stray '\195' in program
./QThread:16: error: stray '\199' in program
./QThread:16: error: stray '\144' in program
./QThread:16:252: warning: null character(s) ignored
./QThread:16: error: stray '@' in program
./QThread:16: error: stray '\139' in program
./QThread:16: error: stray '\16' in program
./QThread:16: error: stray '\240' in program
./QThread:16: error: stray '\255' in program
./QThread:16: error: stray '\8' in program
./QThread:16: error: stray '\15' in program
./QThread:16: error: stray '\149' in program
./QThread:16: error: stray '\194' in program
./QThread:16: error: stray '\132' in program
./QThread:16: error: stray '\210' in program
./QThread:16: error: stray '\139' in program
./QThread:16: error: expected declaration before '}' token
In file included from main.cpp:3:
mythread.h:1:1: unterminated #ifndef
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

`QThread` is the executable. When I delete it and run `make` again, it compiles ok. But when I do some changes `make` gives me the same error. I am creating `Makefile` using `qmake`, why the executable does not regenerated?

```
QThread.pro
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (2.01a) Mon Jan 21 10:22:12 2013
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = 

# Input
HEADERS += mythread.h
SOURCES += main.cpp mythread.cpp
```

Comment: It seems to me your editor saves files in the mode that is not supported by parser. Check saving options.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your .pro file?  It looks like maybe the compiler is trying to compile a .o file as if it was C++ source code.  The .pro file should contain a list of .cpp files in your program, not .o files.  Also it may be unwise to name your executable QThread, since that is also the name of a Qt class; perhaps that is confusing something in the qmake/make system.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I changed program name and it works, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `mythread.h` does `#include <QThread>`, and when your own executable is named `QThread`, this finds the executable you've just built instead of Qt's own header.

You've renamed the program in response to Jeremy's comment and you've seen that it then works. That's one good option. Another is to make sure you include `<QThread>` instead of `"QThread"` (if you aren't doing so already) and make sure your compiler flags are set such that the current directory is not searched before Qt's header directory.